# Is it possible to write C++ template that won't accept any type?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm curious if it's possible to write such C++ template for which it's impossible to create a class/type it will accept (compile without errors).
If it is possible, what it could be?

Comment: Why might you want to do this?

Comment: I know it would be the most useless template. I was just curious if it's possible.

Comment: It might be useful in compiler testing.  It could also potentially useful in software configuration before compiling to identify mutant cases.  I was wondering if you were up to something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct S {
    static_assert(std::is_class<T>::value, "T must be a class");
    static_assert(!std::is_class<T>::value, "T must not be a class");
};
```

However, such a template is automatically ill-formed NDR.

> If no valid specialization can
>   be generated for a template, and that template is not instantiated, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic
>   required.

([temp.res]/8)

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do that is provide a forward declaration of the class template only. One example of such a class template that I have used in the past is to print the size of a type as a compiler error.

```
template <size_t> struct PrintSize;

PrintSize<sizeof(int)> a;
```

When you compile that code, you will be able to tell the size of `int` from the error message issued by the compiler.